# In google AppsScripts howto fetch users Email or ID whos editing the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We do keep up with googlesheet. So to help the team I've made our sheets more automated and everything worked well for time. The signature stamp stopped to work a while ago, and tried to find different solutions for this before asking on my free time.

This is our first on to fetch names, but nowdays does not work.

```
function whatsMyName() 
{
var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var self = false;
if (self) 
{
var name = self.getGivenName();
if (!name)
{
name = self.getFullName();
}
return name;
}
else 
{
var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
return userName;
}
}
```

Been tried different kind of solutions like this found here:

```
function getCurrentUserEmail()
{  
var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

if (userEmail === '' || !userEmail || userEmail === undefined) 
{         
userEmail = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('userEmail');         
if (!userEmail) 
{             
var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').protect();
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());             
var editors = protection.getEditors();             
if (editors.length === 2) 
{                 
var owner = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getOwner();                 
editors.splice(editors.indexOf(owner), 1);             
}             
userEmail = editors\[0\];             
protection.remove();             
PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('userEmail', userEmail);         
}     
}     
return userEmail; 
}
```

Pretty much this did return our "owner" of sheet, not user.
Is there somekind of workaround for this anymore?

So most of those tips and tricks I've found seems to be outdated and not usable anymore.

Trying to reCode this back in action, without win here.

Edit; Trigger on this is

```
function onEdit()
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if (s.getName() == "exampleSheet")
{
if (r.getColumn() == 6) //Cell we check for finished job
{
var nCell = r.offset(0, -4);
if (nCell.getValue() == "")
{
name = whatsMyName();
if(name === "example@eMail.com")
{
nCell.setValue("EI");
}
}
}
}"
```

So after checking that work is done, code should stamp initials to Column2, time and date stamps works, coloring the background works etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide the context of your function? How is it executed?

Comment: Goin to add that to main post! But trigger is onEdit(). First one worked like a charm before. Now it returns as a blank/null. Only with the owner of the sheet it returns as it should be and stamp his initials, but for rest of us its just empty.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610745/onedit-trigger-doesnt-catch-current-user

Comment: Oh, Im goin to check it out today and if so delete this then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my automated sheets I always use *'Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()'* to stamp the person editing the cell, however I use this as part of an *'onEdit()'* function. I am not sure if it would work when it comes from a dedicated function.
Where are you planning on using it?

Comment: Trigger is 'onEdit()' function also. Even this way it still returns as blank/null for rest of us. Ofc it works for owner of the sheet and his initials is stamped as it should be.